# Sorting 3 dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have three dimensional int array(cube) consists of matrices. My problem is, that i want to make a new three dimensional array, where I would have sorted matrices by highest value with insertion sort. I don't want to save values in new cube, but i want to save **only the number** of matrix. Here is some example, how I want to do. Hope you understand my idea:

```
int[][] matrix1={{10,50,10},{3,5,1},{100,500,800}};
int[][] matrix2={{30,30,30},{3,3,3},{300,300,300}};
int[][] matrix3={{20,20,20},{2,2,2},{200,200,200}};
int[][][] nonSortedMatrices={matrix1,matrix2,matrix3};
```

now i want to sorted this way:

```
int[][] matrixWithHighestValue={{2,1,2},{2(or 1),1,2},{2,1,1}};
int[][] matrixSecHighestValue={{3,2,3},{1(or2),2,3},{3,2,2}};
int[][] matrixWithLowestValue={{1,3,1},{3,3,1},{1,3,3}};
int[][][] sortedMatrices={matrixWithHighestValue,matrixSecHighestValue,matrixWithLowestValue};
```

and thats it. Hope it's clear. Matrix `matrixWithHighestValue` would contains on each place the best choice for each place from three(in this case) matrices I am thinking how to do for a couple hours and i can't solve that. Only think what i want to use is an insertion sort,because it is the the fastest way, because the data are not so big.
I would be very grateful for every advice.

Comment: When you say "only the number of matrix", you want the index, right?

Comment: The way you've described it, it sounds like sortedMatrices should really only be a 1d array of ints. Like if you found that matrix2 > matrix1 > matrix3 you would want: `int[] sortedIndices = {2, 1, 3]'.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I want to write like this because i think it is more  easy to understand

Comment: no, i don't want to sort matrices. I want to save the best item on each place

Comment: so it would be different for each place so it must be new 3d array

Comment: I would think once you figure how the sub-problem of turning `10, 30, 20` into `2, 3, 1` for (highest, second highest, lowest) this would be fairly straight-forward.

Comment: in this case which you described is clear because 2(second matrix) has the highest value-30 so i save it into matrixWithHighestValue on [0,0], because it is the best Value for this place and the second best is 20(which is value from matrix 3), so i save 3 into secHighestValueMatrix  on the same place[0,0] and on the same place to the lowestValueMatrix i save the remaining value-10 which is from first matrix so i save number 1 and thats how i want to save it for each position, so i create 3d array

Comment: Yeah, I know what you want to do "by hand," but you are essentially finding the n-th largest maximum for all sub-arrays.

Comment: Yes and i want to save it into next 3d array, so my suggestion is that i will loop through each coordinate in the matrix and i would compare the items in each matrix on the specific coordinates and afterwards i will save it into new 3d array but i don't know exactly how to change algorithm insertion sort for this case to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to "insertion sort". Or why you want to use insertion sort. All sorting algorithms should have the same output; they sort. Using `Collections.sort` is sufficient and is not insertion sort.

Comment: Yes, but it is not so fast as i want, all this problem what i solve is only to speed up my algorithm and i want to use insertion sort because if the values would be sorted, the complexity is for smaller data even faster than quick sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This assumes all the matrices have the same dimensions.

I was having a difficult time thinking of a simplistic way to sort (10, 30, 20) into index-order of (highest, second-highest, lowest), or (2, 3, 1), but this inner class + helper method approach seemed to do that nicely.

The main method scans through the unsorted matrix and build the sorted matrix at the same time.

```
public class MatrixSorter {

    static class IntPos {
        public int num, pos;

        IntPos(int num, int pos) {
            this.num = num;
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // For testing purposes to use Arrays.toString
            return String.valueOf(pos + 1);
        }
    }

    private static int[] getSortedPositions(int[] nums) {
        IntPos[] positions = new IntPos[nums.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            positions[i] = new IntPos(nums[i], i);
        }

        Arrays.sort(positions, new Comparator<IntPos>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(IntPos o1, IntPos o2) {
                return -1 * Integer.compare(o1.num, o2.num);
            }
        });

        int[] sortedPos = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sortedPos[i] = positions[i].pos + 1;
        }

        return sortedPos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix1 = {{10, 50, 10}, {3, 5, 1}, {100, 500, 800}};
        int[][] matrix2 = {{30, 30, 30}, {3, 3, 3}, {300, 300, 300}};
        int[][] matrix3 = {{20, 20, 20}, {2, 2, 2}, {200, 200, 200}};
        int[][][] nonSortedMatrices = {matrix1, matrix2, matrix3};

        final int MATRIX_SIZE = nonSortedMatrices.length;
        int[][][] sortedMatrices = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

        for (int r = 0; r < MATRIX_SIZE; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < MATRIX_SIZE; c++) {

                int[] nums = new int[MATRIX_SIZE];
                for (int d = 0; d < MATRIX_SIZE; d++) {
                    nums[d] = nonSortedMatrices[d][r][c];
                }
                int[] sortedPos = getSortedPositions(nums);

                for (int d = 0; d < MATRIX_SIZE; d++) {
                    sortedMatrices[d][r][c] = sortedPos[d];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Printing out the sorted matrix looks like so

```
for (int r = 0; r < MATRIX_SIZE; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < MATRIX_SIZE; c++) {
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(sortedMatrices[r][c]) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs what looks like what you wanted in the question without the individual `int[][]` values.

```
[2, 1, 2] [1, 1, 2] [2, 1, 1] 
[3, 2, 3] [2, 2, 3] [3, 2, 2] 
[1, 3, 1] [3, 3, 1] [1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but it is too slow for my problem. I dont want to use collections, because they are for speeding up very bad. Anyway i had the same idea what you have but i hope that there is some way how to solve it how i was saying. Thanks for your help

Comment: The only reason I used collections is because I didn't know how to sort an array with a custom Comparator. Internally an ArrayList uses an Array, so I don't understand the concern.

Comment: @Prone66 If you want to stick with arrays, though, I have updated the `getSortedPositions` method.

Comment: Thank you for ur help. Nice job buddy. Must to look on it tomorrow, now i am happy if i can see on the keyboard:))